# Ultrasonic range sonars mapping in RVIZ

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, rviz, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a map in RVIZ, by using 3 ultarsonic sonars. After some research i found some related work, for example in lego [nxt](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt) where it was used an ultrasonic range sonar [here](http://youtu.be/2We5_Qeapbc). And is possible to see in their presentation video doing some mapping in occupancy grid form, but i couldn't found how they do it. Possible using [slam_gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping), but i notice that stack requires laser scans. Any idea how can i do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30257/ultrasonic-range-sonars-mapping-in-rviz/) by [Andre Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1209/andre-araujo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Andre Araujo, for this you need assisted teleoperation to work. The tutorial is here [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_assisted_teleop/Tutorials/Assisted%20Teleop%20Video%20Demo) (Need extra gyro and accelerometer sensor to get better results)

For slam_gmapping you need 3 inputs, laser scans, tf and clock. I am attempting to use kinect and nxt to do slam_gmapping since I don't have the gyro and accelerometer sensor.

However I am stuck with the need to input the clock.

---

Originally posted by [Torres](https://answers.ros.org/users/2035/torres/) with karma: 112 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andre Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1209/andre-araujo/) on 2012-03-22**:
Thanks for the tip, i found the node i'm looking for in (nxt_apps). I want to use it on a custom robot, not in a nxt. I have to do some code modifications to work with my robot, and them test it, hope to achieve good results.

**Comment by [Torres](https://answers.ros.org/users/2035/torres/) on 2012-03-23**:
Good luck and all the best to you.